# An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. (Only in IIS, works fine in VS Web Server)

Tags: c#, .net, iis

I'm getting the infamous "Could not load file or assembly 'MyProject' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format. "

System.BadImageFormatException

I am at a loss on how to figure out the problem.  When I change all references in the project to x86, x64, and Any CPU I still get this problem.  It is strange because I have only seen this error when there is a platform difference between the dll references.  In my case there doesn't seem to be one.

This works fine when I am using the Visual Studio web server.  I have recently switched to use IIS locally and now I have this problem when starting to run my app.  It's a silverlight/ASP.NET app.

Any ideas on how this could be possible related to IIS?

Comment: More information is required.  It sounds like you have not uploaded all the required files.

Comment: No, more information is not required.  Your assumption is incorrect.

Comment: The answer required some more digging and research that you missed.  There was no information mssing from the question.  The problem was in the AppPool I was using.  Enable 32-bit applications needed to be set to True in the AppPool.

Comment: @user1060500 Yes, that means that one of the libraries you use is 32 bit only.  This is the error you see when you try to load 32 bit code into a 64 bit process (enable 32-bit forces IIS to create the worker process as 32 bit, instead of always the default 64 bit).

Answer (score 0):

I had an instance of an obscure problem like this and found that the problem was a (much) lower-level dependent assembly was specifically an X64 assembly, while my assembly was tagged for AnyCPU. You might break out the CORFLAGS utility and start inspecting assemblies to ensure they really are the platform you expect them to be.

Comment: I did that and didn't find any issues.  I found the solution, but I can't post it until tomorrow due to Stackoverflow rules.